# Counting the numbers in an interval within a series of numbers

Tags: c++, while-loop

So I have a series of numbers that will stop when you input a number that is divisible by 3.
I have to count the numbers from this series that are also included in a set interval (eg. [a,b] ) and then show them.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned n, a, b, k = 0, x;
    cout << "a="; cin >> a;
    cout << "b="; cin >> b;
    cout << "n="; cin >> n;
    while(!(n % 3 == 0))
    {
        if (a < n && n < b)
        {
            k++;
            x = n;
        }

        cout << "n="; cin >> n;
    }

    cout << "No. of numbers from the interval " << k << endl;
    cout << "The numbers from the interval " << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I input for example 7 numbers, it will show me the value of `k` `6` and the of `x` `4294967294`.
For `a` and `b` I used the values `1` and `79` and I only gave `n` values from `1` to `20`.

Comment: You never set `x`, so it's unsurprising it gives that kind of result.

Comment: @chris I tried to give x the value of n when it's in that interval, but apparently it didn't work :/

Comment: You have it backwards then. You're giving `n` the value of `x`.

Comment: I did try as you said, but it's still giving me the same. It only shows the last number before I input the number divisible by 3.

Comment: To get the **numbers** from an interval you need to use an array.

Comment: Well.. I didn't learn this yet at class... Could you make a post with the changes for the current code?

Comment: See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/).

Comment: And how can I select the start and end of the array? Take my `a` and `b` at the start of my code for example. I want to input the start of it from within the program, instead of initializing it in the code.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay Well, i think i managed to do it by writing `arr [2]={a,b}`. How can i use the array as a condition? For example `if(n belongs to arr)` bla bla.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help: https://ideone.com/Ig8PEd

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    unsigned n, a, b;
    std::cout << "a="; std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "b="; std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << "n="; std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> v;
    while (n % 3 != 0) {
        if (a < n && n < b) {
            v.push_back(n);
        }
        std::cout << "n="; std::cin >> n;
    }

    std::cout << "No. of numbers from the interval " << v.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The numbers from the interval:" << std::endl;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does work, but more than half of this code I don't understand. I'm quite the begginner in C++. Also, by writing `using namespace std` after typing the libraries wouldn't remove the necessity to write std:: before every code line? :)

Comment: You may have problem with `using namespace std` (name conflict). `std::vector<int>` is a dynamic array of type `int`. `push_back` appends the *new value* at the end. `v.size()` returns the number of element of the array. `v[i]` returns the `i`_th element of the array.